# How to get django session data with javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, session

i save session data in django with key 'theme' :

```
request.session['theme'] = 'light'
```

Then i want to get 'theme' session data in javascript with this code:

```
sessionStorage.getItem("theme");
```

but i can't get theme data.

How can I do this?

Comment: `var theme="{{request.session.theme}}"`

Comment: Pass your session data to the template context in your view. Either directly or by using a context processor.

Comment: @ThiernoAmadouSow It doesn't work

Comment: could you please show your template where you are calling ? this `var theme="{{request.session.theme}}"`  should work actually.

Comment: @dgw in this case it is not a good idea to pass the session data in the template context in the views , because if he has a lot of views then he has to pass it in all of them .I think if he wants to change the theme it is better for him to put this `var theme="{{request.session.theme}}"` in his `base.html by exemple` so that he can extend it to others template. as you said a context processor is also an amazing idea.